# How to convert string with xml tags into dictionary using split function or more generic ways in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string which is actually a big xml structure string.
I want convert this string into dictionary so that I can quickly grab the key value pair. How can I do so and what is the way here?

I am using python3.

```
<TDS xmlns="http://uburw">
     <odour>
       <state>
         <order-number>AE:9E:7A:4E:8A:15</order-number>
        <oper-order-age>600</oper-order-age>
         <oper-order-time>200</oper-order-time>
        <oper-order-delay>1500</oper-order-delay>
         <branch-root>80008e5d3c4d1572</branch-root>
        <branch-root-path-cost>200000000</branch-root-path-cost>
         <branch-root-interface>20</branch-root-interface>
         <branch-root-if>
           <branch-base-name>ge2</branch-base-name>
           <branch-ext-id/>
         </branch-root-if>
        <time-since-top-change>191816</time-since-top-change>
         <function-changes>1</function-changes>
         <branch-root-hops>1</branch-root-hops>
       </state>
   <leaves>
        <leaf>
          <leaf-name>ge1</leaf-name>
         </leaf>
        <leaves>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far?... See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46041928/7545157) as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

[xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) does this and its pretty easy.

Example:

```
xmltodict.parse("""
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<person>
  <name>john</name>
  <age>20</age>
</person>""")
```

Output:

```
{u'person': {u'age': u'20', u'name': u'john'}}
```